# How to check column value is in order or not in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have one dataframe like below -

```
               time              machine        message
6      2017-08-07 05:24:31,955    solid    qa  : 6502444
20     2017-08-07 05:24:32,024    solid    prod : 6502445
32     2017-08-07 05:24:32,033    solid    qa : 6502445
44     2017-08-07 05:24:32,041    solid    prod : 6502446
56     2017-08-07 05:24:32,055    solid    qa : 6502446
68     2017-08-07 05:24:32,063    solid    prod : 6502447
80     2017-08-07 05:24:32,071    solid    qa : 6502450
92     2017-08-07 05:24:32,079    solid    prod : 6502451
92     2017-08-07 05:24:32,079    solid    qa : 6502452
104    2017-08-07 05:24:32,086    solid    prod : 6502453
116    2017-08-07 05:24:32,094    liquid    qa : 700001
128    2017-08-07 05:24:32,101    liquid    prod : 700004
140    2017-08-07 05:24:32,108    liquid    qa : 700002
152    2017-08-07 05:24:32,115    liquid    prod : 700005
164    2017-08-07 05:24:32,126    liquid    qa : 700007
176    2017-08-07 05:24:32,133    liquid    prod : 700010
188    2017-08-07 05:24:32,140    liquid    qa : 700008
200    2017-08-07 05:24:32,147    liquid    prod : 700011
```

I want to know what numbers are missing in the message field for particular qa and prod. If any number is missing then I want how many numbers are missing, previous available start time and next available end time with respective message numbers.

I want to generate one output file in csv format which has header like below -

```
machine,message_header,missing_number_size,start,end,start_time,end_time
```

- **machine** is solid or liquid (in this case i.e. if 3rd one available then that need to take in account).
- **message_header** is available in the message column values. It is fixed either qa or prod.
- **missing_number_size** is the numbers which get missed in between for qa and prod as well.
- **start** is last available number before missed from message column.
- **end** is first available number after missed from message column.
- **start_time** is last available time before missed from time column.
- **end_time** is first available time after missed from time column.

**Output.csv** will look like this -

```
machine,message_info,missin_number_size,start,end,start_time,end_time
solid,qa,3,6502446,6502450,2017-08-07 05:24:32,055,2017-08-07 05:24:32,071
solid,qa,1,6502450,6502452,2017-08-07 05:24:32,071,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079
solid,prod,3,6502447,6502451,2017-08-07 05:24:32,063,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079
solid,prod,1,6502451,6502453,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079,2017-08-07 05:24:32,086
liquid,qa,4,700002,700007,2017-08-07 05:24:32,108,2017-08-07 05:24:32,126
liquid,prod,4,700005,700010,2017-08-07 05:24:32,115,2017-08-07 05:24:32,133
```

How I can check the order of message column and generate above csv file?

Comment: When you say _what numbers are missing_ do you mean out of all positive integers?  Or from a list elsewhere?  Or using the first and last entries and upper and lower bounds?

Comment: @user1717828- number is missing when it is not in sequence i.e. after 6502446 (solid/qa) number we are expecting 6502447 as (solid/qa) only but it is not available meant it's missing. Got clarity?